# Opencart error Map Show empty and avatar

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

The avatar and map disappeared in here: http://togo-online.com/index.php?route=common/store

Undefined index: route in /home/ten1356/public_html/togo-online.com/catalog/controller/module/storelocator.php on line 391

Undefined index: seller_id in /home/ten1356/public_html/togo-online.com/catalog/controller/module/storelocator.php on line 498

Undefined variable: av in /home/ten1356/public_html/togo-online.com/catalog/controller/module/storelocator.php on line 506

Error:
391: 
if ($this->request->get['route'] == 'product/product' && $showEmptyMap == 'false' && count($store_list) == 0) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        return TRUE;

498: 
$avatars = $this->model_module_storelocator->getStoreAvatar($store['seller_id']);

506:

$avatarNode = $dom->createElement('avatar',$av);

What will be the solution to this error..Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first two errors, it is telling you those indexes don't exist in the arrays. I'm assuming `$this->route->get` is supposed to be an associative array, but it is not finding `'route'` in that array at the point you are accessing it. This is also the case with `$store['seller_id']`.

The third error is saying you haven't defined the variable `$av` which you are passing to the function `createElement`. Check your code before this call and make sure that variable gets set.

In terms of exactly how to fix these errors, there is really no way (for us) to know without seeing the rest of the code and what is happened before reaching each of these points.

Comment: I use storelocator in this site and VQMod Manager...do you think there are other problem that affects the show empty map..?

Comment: last two weeks ago the map show then its empty but i didn't edit any code.

Comment: Maybe someone else changed the code? Or something must have updated automatically causing the functionality to change. I'd be blindly guessing at this point. Ideally, you would need to post the rest of the code from the `storelocator.php` file (or a majority of it) in order to give some more context to what is going on before those errors are thrown.

Comment: Before the map show empty...i get a ISE500 errors...then i delete and upload the .htaccess then the map disappear and some debug...so i put the output_buffering = On; in php.ini...then the debug is gone but the map disappear us same...

Comment: do you think the ISE500 error is the reason of why map is show empty..is there any code to put in php.ini that can help the system like  output_buffering = On; for debug problem...other code for avatar and map disappearance...

Comment: The map in Homepage is ok but in http://togo-online.com/index.php?route=common/store is not...